# Vue.js nested ref, method is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a 3 level deep component setup that looks like this.

```
- container
  - section-1 // section1Ref
    - form-1 // form1Ref
```

The container component will trigger the `submit` method in the `section-1` via `this.$refs.section1Ref.submit()`.

The `submit` method in the **section component** will then call the `submit` method in the `form-1` component like `this.$refs.form1Ref.submit()`

I am getting this error in `this.$refs.form1Ref.submit()` invokation.

> this.$refs.form1Ref.submit is not a function

Tho I am 100% sure that it's defined in the `methods` object of the `form-1` component.

I noticed that this is happening when the ref is 3 levels deep.

Comment: IMO using $refs like this is an anti pattern. try using event instead https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

Comment: Thanks @JacobGoh I want the top most or the parent container to trigger all of the submit for it's child components. Would mind suggesting a way of using events?

Comment: I had a similar issue, when I have multiple elements referenced, the child elements don't initialize as refs. I think having them all as separate components would work because it will wait to initialize things at each layer, but when they're all in the same component it seems to break. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: It turns out that the v-for keys on my array of components were being initialized too late which broke the refs somehow. After ensuring that the v-for array keys existed in the objects the refs were defined for me.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, Here is my sample code

```js
Vue.component('sec', {
  template: `
  <div>section
    <br>
    <form1 ref="form"></form1>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    callSection() {
      this.$refs.form.callForm();
    }
  }
});
Vue.component('form1', {
  template: `<div>form</div>`,
  methods: {
    callForm() {
      console.log('am called inside form')
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('container', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <button @click="clickMe">Click me</button>
    <br>
    <sec ref="section"></sec>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    clickMe() {
      this.$refs.section.callSection();
    }
  }
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <container />
</div>
```